# How do I initialize a struct inside struct with members variables?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I defined a struct called `Object` and, inside this struct there are 3 more structs.

The `collision_box` should be tied together with `position` and `size`. Whenever I update the position and size, the `collision_box` should get the same values.

Before that I was just copying the position and size values to `collision_box` in the Init and Update function. It was working fine, but I think this should also work with pointers so I don't have to copy the values every time.

```
// Object definition 
typedef struct Object{
    Vector2 position; // typedef struct float x,y
    Vector2 size;     // typedef struct float x,y

    // When ever I update position and size the collision_box should get the same values
    // without copying them in the Update function.
    Rectangle collision_box = {position.x, position.y, size.x, size.y}; // typedef struct float x,y,width,height

}Object;

// Extension of Object
typedef struct Player{
    Object* o;
}Player;

// Update Players position and size
void UpdatePlayer(Player* player)
{
    player->o->position = (Vector2){100.0f, 100.0f};
    player->o->size = (Vector2){20.0f, 20.0f};
}

// player.o->collision_box should always be tied to player.o->position and player.o->size
printf("%f/n", player.o->collision_box.x);  
printf("%f/n", player.o->collision_box.y);
printf("%f/n", player.o->collision_box.width);  
printf("%f/n", player.o->collision_box.height);
```

**Output**

```
100.0
100.0
20.0
20.0
```

Comment: Why would you have essentially exactly the same info in two places? Especially within the same object. Doesn't seem like a good design. Write a `getCollisionBox` function that returns the required struct from an `Object` (or vice versa) if you really need the info in that from.

Comment: copying a struct of 2 floats is going to be very efficient. Your only other choice it to have `Object` use a pointer to a `Vector2` thats on the heap. Now you have the cost of indirection all the time and you have to deal with heap lifecycle

Comment: Probably I'm overthinking this a bit... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could declare your `Object` [as a `union`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/union), rather than as a `struct`, with the `position` and `size` members themselves being enclosed in an inner, anonymous structure.

That way, the two `Vector2` types will occupy the same memory as the `Rectangle` member, and any changes to the former will also be made to the latter (and *vice versa*):

```c
typedef union tagObject {
    struct {
        Vector2 position, size;
    };
    Rectangle collision_box;
}Object;
```

This gives you the ability to refer to the data either through the `position` and `size` members, or through the `collision_box` member.

Test code (correcting your `/n` to `\n` and adding some local variables to the `main` function so that it works):

```c
int main()
{
    Player player;
    Object object;
    player.o = &object;
    UpdatePlayer(&player);
    // player.o->collision_box should always be tied to player.o->position and player.o->size
    printf("%f\n", player.o->collision_box.x);
    printf("%f\n", player.o->collision_box.y);
    printf("%f\n", player.o->collision_box.width);
    printf("%f\n", player.o->collision_box.height);
}
```

Output:

```
100.000000
100.000000
20.000000
20.000000
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and correcting my code, its working great!